# PHP: Compare the start of two strings

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

I am wondering if there is a simple way to, in PHP, compare two strings and returns the amount of characters they have in common from the start of the string.

An example:

```
$s1 =  "helloworld";
$s1 =  "hellojohn";
```

These two strings both start with 'hello', which means that both strings have the first 5 characters in common. '5' is the value I'd like to recieve when comparing these two strings.

Is there a computationally fast way of doing this without comparing both strings as arrays to eachother?

Comment: From my knowledge, I don't think there is a built in function for something like this. Most likely, you will have to make your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function commonChars($s1, $s2) {
    $IMAX = min(strlen($s1), strlen($s2));
    for($i = 0; $i < $IMAX; $i++)
        if($s2[i] != $s1[i]) break;
    return $i;
}
```

Comment: You should precompute `min(strlen($s1), strlen($s2))` before the loop, so it's not recomputed at **every** iteration.

Comment: Thank you joeframbach, you're absolutely right. it's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are really big, then I would write my own binary search. Something similar to this totally untested code that I just dreamed up.

```
function compareSection($start, $end, $string1, $string2) {
  $substr1 = substr($string1, $start, $end-$start);
  $substr2 = substr($string2, $start, $end-$start);
  if ($substr1 == $substr2) return $end;
  if ($firstMatches = compareSection(0, $end/2, $substr1, $substr2)) {
    return $start + $firstMatches;
  if ($lastMatches = compareSection($end/2, $end, $substr, $substr2)) {
    return $start+$lastMatches;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the similarity of the strings you wish to get and not just the actual number of identical characters, there are two functions for that:[strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) and [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php). Maybe they suit your goal more than what you asked for in this question.

Comment: It's likely that this is what they actually want.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, I don't think there is a built in function for something like this. Most likely, you will have to make your own.

Shouldn't be too hard. Just loop both strings by index by index until you don't find a match that doesn't match. However far you got is the answer.

Hope that helps!